# Array not working properly when removing data in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have a grid view and loop data from an array called **objEntityType: EntityTypeVM;** also I have created another an array equal to **objEntityType** as original dataset **objEntityTypeOriginal: EntityTypeVM;**

on search method, I'm filtering data on objEntityTypeOriginal and assign it to objEntityType.

But the problem is whatever I do to objEntityType same thins happen to objEntityTypeOriginal.

about my code below, In OnSearch() I need to search text so before that I need to empty the **objEntityType** But after I empty the objEntityType **objEntityTypeOriginal** also will empty.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityTypeVM, EntityType, Entity, ApiResponseModel } from '../../../shared/models';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-entity-create',
  templateUrl: './entity-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entity-create.component.scss']
})

export class EntityCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  private objEntityTypeOriginal: EntityTypeVM;
  private objEntityType: EntityTypeVM;
  
   constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   
    this.searchText = '';
    this.objEntityType = new EntityTypeVM();
    this.objEntityType.entities = [{ value: '001', synonyms: ['home', 'house']}];//this will replace with API data
   this.objEntityTypeOriginal =  = this.objEntityType; 
  }
  
  
    EnterEntitySynonymsHandler(event: KeyboardEvent, index: number, synonym: string) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && synonym) {
      this.objEntityType.entities[index].synonyms.push(synonym);
      this.objEntityType.entities[index].newSynonym = '';
       this.objEntityTypeOriginal =  = this.objEntityType; 
    }
  }
  
  RemoveSynonymItem(entityIndex, synonymIndex) {
    this.objEntityType.entities[entityIndex].synonyms.splice(synonymIndex, 1);
      this.objEntityTypeOriginal =  = this.objEntityType; 
  }
  
   // ----- problem In below method  -----------------------
  OnSearch() {
    const searchText = this.searchText.toLowerCase();

    if (searchText === '') {
      this.objEntityType = this.objEntityTypeOriginal;
    } else { 
  
      this.objEntityType.entities = [];//After this line .objEntityTypeOriginal.entities also will be empty.    
      this.objEntityTypeOriginal.entities.forEach(element => {
        const itemAsString =JSON.stringify(element).toLowerCase();
        if (itemAsString.indexOf(searchText) !== -1) {
          this.objEntityType.entities.push(element);
        }
      });
    }
   }
  
  }
```

Comment: Assuming the actual code is `this.objEntityTypeOriginal = this.objEntityType;`, this doesn't create a copy of the object. It assigns the object referenced by this.objEntityType to this.objEntityTypeOriginal. Those are thus two references to the same object. So when you modify the object referenced by on of the variables, the object referenced by the other is also modified: they both reference the exact same object.

Comment: Yes. whatever I do to one object same thing happens to other object. What is the solution for that..?

Comment: Create a copy of the object (end its entities array) instead of just assigning it to another variable.

Comment: It worked thank you..